# how to use @Valid with update for springboot

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

this Person.java  it has valid

```
@Entity
@Data
@DynamicUpdate
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull(message = "姓名必填字段")
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "地址必填字段")
    private String address;
```

Controller.java it use valid

```
    @PostMapping("/person")
public Result<Person> personAdd(@Valid Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return ResultUtil.error(1, bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
    }
    return ResultUtil.success(personService.save(person));
}

    @PutMapping("/person/2")
    public Result personAdd2(@RequestBody Person person) throws PersonException {
//        Person resultPerson = personService.findOne(person.getId());
//        BeanUtils.copyProperties(resultPerson,person);
        return ResultUtil.success(personService.save(person));

    }
```

Test.java it's error

```
 @Test
public void testPersonAdd2() throws Exception{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId(2);
    person.setName("marry");
    String responseString = mvc.perform(put("/person/2")
            .content(asJsonString(person))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    log.info(responseString);
```

error:

```
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='地址必填字段', propertyPath=address, rootBeanClass=class cn.merryyou.logback.domain.Person, messageTemplate='地址必填字段'}
```

I need when save valid but update is not valid. what should I do

the code: [logback](https://github.com/longfeizheng/logback)
my English is pool

Comment: Easiest is to have two end points for add and edit like `POST /persons` for add and `POST /persons/{id}` for edit. This way you can handle both of them independently. You can reuse your data access layer classes in both the places

Comment: I don't understand: where do you invoke the validation process in the "/person/2" mapping?

Comment: i don't use @valid,but the jpa check it ,you can download code run it

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla the edit should be `PUT`, not `POST`

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way, but not a hard and fast rule. As long as we have the `{id}` in the URL we are sure that any number of times the same API is invoked, it will just update the given id with the given data

Comment: when i update person,i shoud   search it ,and then update like this code `Person resultPerson = personService.findOne(person.getId());
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(resultPerson,person);  personService.save(p)`